# Interfacing rosjava with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to convert a sensor_msgs/Image message to IplImage format in rosjava? Is there an equivalent of cvBridge in java?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67740/interfacing-rosjava-with-opencv/) by [Willson Amalraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/5060/willson-amalraj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 206 on 2013-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you take a look at [OpenCV now supports desktop Java](http://www.willowgarage.com/blog/2013/02/19/opencv-now-supports-desktop-java)?

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Willson Amalraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/5060/willson-amalraj/) on 2013-07-23**:
Thanks for the reply. I did take a look at OpenCV for Java previously. But decided to stick with JavaCV. Maybe I'll see if it can decode sensor_msgs/Image message.